# Determine if user provided a directory, a file, a full path or something else

Tags: powershell

This is an issue that I have been encountering over the year and I could never arrive at a complete solution for it, despite my efforts. Thus as a result a have bunch of commands/modules that don't follow any consistent pattern for how  a destination path can be provided.

I wonder if there exists common solutions for it.

I need the user (or myself) to provide a value to a "destination" parameter but allow it to be done in a manner that is flexible, such as to be able to:

- Only provide a file name (with extension), in which case I will use `$pwd` to construct a full path
- Only provide a file name (with no extension), in which case I will use `$pwd` and the input files extension (`-Path` value) to construct a full path
- Only provide a directory path, such as `c:\temp`, in which case I will derive the file name from the input file (`-Path` value)
- Provide a relative path
- Provide a full path

The following would be typical invocations I have in mind:

```
NewSnippetFrom-Video -Path "c:\vid\LongVideo.mp4" <options> Destination "-Destination "ShortVideo" 
NewSnippetFrom-Video -Path "c:\vid\LongVideo.mp4" <options> Destination "-Destination "ShortVideo.mp4" 
NewSnippetFrom-Video -Path "c:\vid\LongVideo.mp4" <options> Destination "-Destination "\ShortVideo.mp4"
NewSnippetFrom-Video -Path "c:\vid\LongVideo.mp4" <options> Destination "-Destination ".\ShortVideo.mp4"
NewSnippetFrom-Video -Path "c:\vid\LongVideo.mp4" <options> Destination "-Destination "c:\temp"
NewSnippetFrom-Video -Path "c:\vid\LongVideo.mp4" <options> Destination "-Destination "c:\temp\ShortVideo.mp4"
```

In each time, I have attempted to solve this problem myself, my blocking point was finding a PowerShell function/command that I can use to implement the logic. Today reading the documentation for `test-path` I thought it would do, the documentation says:

> The Test-Path cmdlet determines whether all elements of the path exist...It can also tell whether the path syntax is valid and whether the path leads to a container or a terminal or leaf element

But my test of the command don't bear this out.

```
test-path -path "LongVideo|.mp4" -PathType leaf -IsValid        #Returns True 
test-path -path "c:LongVideo:test.mp4" -PathType leaf -IsValid  #Returns True 
test-path -path "c:LongVideo:\test.mp4" -PathType leaf -IsValid #Returns True
```

With the above examples, I am expecting `-PathType leaf` to test only for the name and extension. `LongVideo|.mp4` or `c:LongVideo:\test.mp4` are not valid file names so why is it telling me its valid?

I am thinking of just using Regular Expressions to just validate the value myself but since I intend to use this as a general purpose "component" for many Commands/PS1/Modules it, I would like an optimal solution.

I would also love to hear or see examples of how this could be handled. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to PowerShell version 6.1.2, there is a problem when `-IsValid` and `-PathType` are used together for validation purposes. ([MSDN PS7.3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path?view=powershell-7.3#-pathtype))

First, if `-IsValid` is specified, the -PathType switch is simply ignored, and furthermore, only syntactic path validation is done.

Second, `-PathType` used by itself tests if the final element in the path is of a particular type, regardless of the path string.
<sub>Here's a great [discussion of the issue on Github](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8607) that gives more details.</sub>

```
test-path -path "LongVideo|.mp4" -PathType leaf         #Returns False 
test-path -path "c:LongVideo:test.mp4" -PathType leaf   #Returns False (and throws "Illegal characters in path" error.)
test-path -path "c:LongVideo:\test.mp4" -PathType leaf  #Returns False
```

You could try to further analyze the path and its parts with `$path -Split "\\"`  and `Split-Path`, however, that sounds like hours of fun.

```
$path = "c:\LongVideo:\sub|\other\test|.mp4"
$pathIntoArray = $path -Split "\\"
$pathIntoArray | ForEach-Object { $cleaned = Remove-InvalidFileNameChars($_);
                                  $cleaned.Equals($_); } #was anything removed?

$pathParent = Split-Path $path -Parent
$pathLeaf = Split-Path $path -Leaf
$pathQualifier = Split-Path $path -Qualifier
$pathIsAbsolute = Split-Path $path -IsAbsolute
$pathIntoArray = @("Parent of the path: $pathParent", 
                   "Leaf of the path: $pathLeaf",
                   "Qualifier of the path: $pathQualifier",
                   "Is the path absolute? (True/False): $pathIsAbsolute")
$pathIntoArray
```

With that in mind, I would probably avoid fiddling around too much and simply make use of try-catch to handle edge cases (and maybe remove illegal characters on your own, e.g. using the function above as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23067832/8291949)).